# error: Snakefile "test/Snakefile" not found

Tags: fasta, pathogen

(PathoFact) pradip@Pady:
snakemake -s test/Snakefile --use-conda --reason --cores 1 -p

```
#############################################
I am getting this....
Error: Snakefile "test/Snakefile" not found.
> 


PathoFact) pradip@Pady:~$ # 
snakemake -s test/Snakefile --use-conda --reason --cores 1 -p

wanted the get rid of that eorror
```